# Visual Studio 2017 fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'Main.cpp'

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am a brand new user of Visual Studio 2017 and I am having difficulty building a simple HelloWorld project. Here's what I am doing:

*File > New > Project...*

I choose **Empty Project**. I rename the project *HelloWorld* and I change the location from the default location on my c drive to a location inside my Dev folder, which is on my d drive. Once the project is created, I right click *Source Files* and add a file called *Main.cpp*, containing the simplest code:

```
int main() {
   return 0;
}
```

However, when I right-click *HelloWorld* and **Build**, I receive the following output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: HelloWorld, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Main.cpp
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'Main.cpp': No such file or directory
1>Done building project "HelloWorld.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

However, I only receive this error if I change the Location of the project. If I use the default directory, **c:\my_user\Source\repos** then the project builds without any issue. But I would like to know how to fix this error, because I don't want to keep my files on my c drive. Has anyone else experienced this problem who might know how to fix it? Because I am at a loss.

**EDIT** According to a Microsoft docs article on Fatal Error C1083:

> An additional cause of this error is case-sensitivity in the file
>   system, either for the file name or path, if per directory case
>   sensitivity is enabled, and the directories were created by the
>   Windows Subsystem for Linux.

This is the case for me. When I bought this laptop, I downloaded all my files, including my Dev folder, from my PC using rsync in Window Subsystem for Linux. So this directory wasn't created by Windows, but by Ubuntu running on WSL. This may be the cause of the problem, but I still don't know how to fix it. Even if it is case sensitive, I am typing the folder with the correct case, so I don't know why it wouldn't work.

**SOLVED** In case anyone else encounters this problem, it was an issue with WSL. I never would have guessed this. If you want to use a folder that was created with WSL for your Visual Studio project, you have to disable case-sensitivity:

1. Run Windows Powershell as admin
2. Run the command:

> fsutil.exe file setCaseSensitiveInfo d:\my_wsl_created_folder disable

This fixed the issue for me!

Comment: I changed the project location inside the New Project dialog directly below Name where it says Location. I clicked **Browse...** and created a new folder in d:\Dev\visual_studio_projects

Comment: Yes, I just checked that the file exists in the same folder as HelloWorld.vcxproj

Comment: Yes, there is one occurrence of Main.cpp in the file:

<ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="Main.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>

Comment: The weird thing is that I just tried to do exactly the same thing on my other computer in Visual Studio 2017 and it works correctly. I'm not sure why it behaves differently on my laptop. Both are running Windows 10.

Comment: After some more troubleshooting, I have discovered that I only get this error when I try to use a folder inside my Dev folder as a location for the Project. For example d:\vs_projects works correctly but d:\Dev\vs_projects does not work. That makes no sense to me at all. Is this some kind of permissions issue? I don't know how Windows permissions work.

Comment: Please add these details in your question not in comments. No need to reply this comment. You may remove your comments after adding the details in your question. Add your answer separately.